# How to install libdb4.8++-dev or equivalent on 13.10?

Tags: installation, 13.10, package-management

I am trying to test a mod that I've created of Peercoin.

I need to install `libdb4.8++-dev`, but it is not available.

How can I install it or an equivalent?

**Note:** this is not a dupe since I cannot install a package of my custom alteration of Peercoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it compiles with `libdb++-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev -y` thanks to [this guy](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/issues/47).

However, "Upstream Bitcoin considers db-4.8 to be the only supported version. 5.1 is known to work, buts databases are incompatible with official builds created with db-4.8."

If mining, add the `-detachdb` flag to `./ppcoin-qt` (probably best to just do it anyway).

Answer (score 8):

From nullnoname answer. Here is what I did for ubuntu 16:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

This repository is not found

> Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu disco Release
>
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

So you can try this method

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.zip
unzip db-4.8.30.zip
cd db-4.8.30
cd build_unix/
../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx
make
make install
```

Also commonly fixes :
libdb_cxx headers missing Ubuntu
found berkeley db other than 4.8, required for portable wallets
berkeley db 4.8 Ubuntu

[reference](https://cryptoandcoffee.com/mining-gems/install-berkeley-4-8-db-libs-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need db-4.8 related packages in Ubuntu 13.10 and newer, they can be installed from [Bitcoin team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin). (**ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin**)

Answer (score 1):

You could compile it from source as well.

`$ wget 'http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz'
$ tar -xzvf db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
$ cd db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix/
$ ../dist/configure --enable-cxx
$ make
$ make install`

Tell your system where to find db4.8

`$ export BDB_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include"
$ export BDB_LIB_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib"
$ ln -s /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/libdb-4.8.so /usr/lib/libdb-4.8.so`

Answer (score 1):

Tell your system where to find db4.8:

```
$ export BDB_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include"

$ export BDB_LIB_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib"

$ ln -s /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/libdb-4.8.so /usr/lib/libdb-4.8.so
```

After 3 hours googling I almost gave up then this one worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
apt update
apt install -y libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

---

currently the ppp:bitcoin is giving some error messages (including key), it may even take sometime to complete the repository inclusion, but it will be ok in the end.
other options as snap may be considered if the error message is a concern

Answer (score 0):

This works for Windowsfx 10 version

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
echo '12edc0df75bf9abd7f82f821795bcee50f42cb2e5f76a6a281b85732798364ef  db-
4.8.30.NC.tar.gz' | sha256sum -c
tar -xvf db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
cd db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
mkdir -p build
BDB_PREFIX=$(pwd)/build

../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx --with-pic --prefix=$BDB_PREFIX
sudo make install -B -i -k
```

```
export BDB_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include"
export BDB_LIB_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib"
ln -s /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/libdb-4.8.so /usr/lib/libdb-4.8.so
```